# If I double a bread recipe do I double the salt?

Tags: bread, salt

I think it was my mom who gave me the rule of thumb that when you double a recipe you double everything except the salt. 
I'm willing to defer to her wisdom for the sorts of soups and stews she liked to make, but she didn't do much baking, and I never saw her make bread leavened with yeast. 
I know salt and yeast aren't friends and I'm trying to double a rustic ciabatta recipe.

Comment: related : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/9458/67

Comment: I cannot think of a basis not to double the salt.

Answer (score 3):

If you’re measuring your ingredients by weight, I don’t see any reason not to double the salt. I usually do. If you’re measuring ingredients by volume, it might be best to err on the less salty side, as different types of salt have different densities. Hope this helps

Comment: How is density different with scale?

Comment: @Paparazzi “lf you’re measuring ingredients by volume” - the poster clearly refers to those cases where cooks don’t weigh.

Comment: @Stephie How does weigh have anything to do with double a recipe?  How will volume be off any different if I double a recipe?  If volume is off by 10% will volume not be off be 10% when a recipe is doubled?

Comment: A cup of AP flour abnd a cup of whole wheat flour. And if you’re measuring out 3 cups, each cup may differently depending on tightly yo pack the cup. A tsp of kosher salt weighs less than a tsp of table salt, but 4 grams of salt is 4 grams, regardless of type. I’m still learning about percentages, so far, it’s worked very well for me.